# Modify subnets to a VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, endpoint, subnet, vpc

I recently turned my two AWS public subnets into private subnets and added a public subnet that's got a NAT gateway. The private subnet routing table routs traffic to the NAT gateway and the public one routs it to the Internet Gateway. However, it isn't working and I don't get response to my API calls.

I think this is due to the fact that my VPC endpoint has the two private subnets associated with it instead of the public subnet. I tried to change the associated private subnets to the public one but got the AWS error:

```
Error modifying subnets
Can't change subnets of a requester-managed endpoint for the service ...
```

What would be the way to get around this error and add my public subnet to the VPC endpoint?

*Additional info: Each private subnet has an EC2 auto-scaling group instance and a serverless aurora DB instance in it.*

Cheers, Kris

Comment: Delete, and create new interface endpoints.

Comment: Got a similar error when trying to delete the VPC endpoint: `Operation is not allowed for requester-managed VPC endpoints for the service`

Comment: What VPC endpoint is that?

Comment: Type: Interface. Service name: vpce.eu-west-2....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is [requester-managed VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requester-managed-eni.html):

> You **cannot** modify or **detach** a requester-managed network interface.

This means that you have to delete the resource that created the endpoint in the first place:

> If you **delete the resource** that the network interface represents, the AWS service detaches and deletes the network interface for you.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this annoying problem. The error messages are not really helpful here. They do not reveal which service exactly created those interfaces. So I went to Cloudtrail, listed all events, and searched for the VPC Endpoint name (vpce-1234567890xxx) that refused to be deleted to find out who created it. In my case, it turned out to be the RDS proxy service. So I went to RDS and deleted the proxy.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!  I had missed the proxy because DB proxies aren't listed in the RDS dashboard, you have to click on "Proxies" ... now my unused endpoints are gone! Hurrah!